# The offset of PopupMenuButton is not working properly in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a list containing `PopupMenuButton` using `ListView.builder`.
And I set the offset to open the popup menu at the desired position in this PopupMenuButton.
However, the popup menu only opens at the offset zero or end of the Row.

```
return ListView.separated(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // popupmenu button widget (list first index)
    if (index == 0) {
      return _buildNewRoom();
    }
    // other widget
    return _buildMyRooms(
      widget.roomModels[index - 1],
      index,
      _controllers[index],
    );
  },

  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return const Divider(
      color: Colors.grey,
    );
  },

  itemCount: widget.roomModels.length + 1,
);
```

// _buildNewRoom (popup menu widget)

```
class CreateMenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isTablet;
  final bool isListStyle1;

  const CreateMenuWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.isTablet,
    required this.isListStyle1,
  }) : super(key: key);
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double _containerWidth = 50;
        double _containerHeight = 70;
    
        return PopupMenuButton<int>(
          color: Colors.grey[100],
          offset: const Offset(0, 100), // offset X problem??
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 200,
          ),
          itemBuilder: _itemList,
          onSelected: _onSeleted,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: _containerWidth,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      size: 28,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: sm_padding,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "New File",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

Offset Y works well, but if offset X is greater than 0, it will always be at the end of the ListTile

Offset(0,100)

[image]

Offset(1,100) or Or a larger value

[image]

Why is the popup menu positioned at the end of ListTile?

Comment: What are you using on listTile to hold this widget

Comment: After testing, it is the same problem even if I remove ListTile.
The code has been modified.

Comment: I've run into the same problem, and I just want the popup centered below a button.